# Is this sound bite in the song Radio from The Avalanches from a Television show?

Tags: meaning

In the song [Radio by Avalanches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHMV2fM9ibo) is the opening sound clip from a TV show? The conversation is below:

```
[Intro]
Johnny, Johnny! Open up
Johnny, it's Frank! Open up
Look you've been in there for three weeks
Now come on, open up
Johnny, Johnny!
Out of my way, I'm watching television
Are you crazy? That's the test pattern
I like it!
Well, there are two things to be done
First of all, we put him in the hospital
And withdraw all television, I see
And then, we give him this... radio
Radio, radio, radio, radio, radio, radio...
```

If so what show is this from?

https://genius.com/The-avalanches-radio-lyrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part consists of excerpts from the sketch **I was a TV Addict, by Wayne & Shuster**, originally in spoken word (the [video version](https://youtu.be/wAfPJmjGTC0?t=523) is newer).
It's about being so addicted to TV even a static test pattern becomes mesmerizing.

I can't find the source of the second part.

Comment: The second part is from the same sketch, just a couple minutes later. Some of the samples from Frontier Psychiatrist ("the man with the golden eyeball", "I felt strangely hypnotized, I was in another world") are also from this sketch

Here's the version they sampled: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EY4wI1Lwc1w